# Dropdown not worked on bootstrap 5.3

Tags: javascript, web, frontend, bootstrapper

I trying to create navigation bar with bootstrap.

I read the docs from [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/getting-started/introduction/), but my drop down not working.

I attached everything in the `<head> <head/>` section but dropdown not worked for me.

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>НИМХ - АС и БД, Филиал - Пловдив</title>
<!-- index.css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/index.css">
<!-- CSS Leaflet-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.3/dist/leaflet.css"
     integrity="sha256-kLaT2GOSpHechhsozzB+flnD+zUyjE2LlfWPgU04xyI="
     crossorigin=""/>
<!-- JS Leaflet -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.3/dist/leaflet.js"
     integrity="sha256-WBkoXOwTeyKclOHuWtc+i2uENFpDZ9YPdf5Hf+D7ewM="
     crossorigin=""></script>
<!-- CSS Bootstrap-->
     <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- JS Bootstrap-->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.6/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-oBqDVmMz9ATKxIep9tiCxS/Z9fNfEXiDAYTujMAeBAsjFuCZSmKbSSUnQlmh/jp3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-mQ93GR66B00ZXjt0YO5KlohRA5SY2XofN4zfuZxLkoj1gXtW8ANNCe9d5Y3eG5eD" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-body-tertiary">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                  Dropdown
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                  <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link disabled">Disabled</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <form class="d-flex" role="search">
              <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
              <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    <div id="map">
        <!-- Load map -->
        <script src="./js/leaflet.js"></script> 
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Can I get example with worked dropdown on bootstrap 5.3 ?

I think I have attached all the necessary libraries for the dropdown menu to work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add Bootstrap's JavaScript as well:

```html
// Add this line before the closing </body> tag
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

i.e.

```html
    <div id="map">
        <!-- Load map -->
        <script src="./js/leaflet.js"></script> 
    </div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap provides you with several stackblitz links to check their templates, like this: https://stackblitz.com/run?file=index.html

Used on your code would be something like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>НИМХ - АС и БД, Филиал - Пловдив</title>
<!-- index.css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/index.css">
<!-- CSS Leaflet-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.3/dist/leaflet.css"
     integrity="sha256-kLaT2GOSpHechhsozzB+flnD+zUyjE2LlfWPgU04xyI="
     crossorigin=""/>
     
<!-- JS Leaflet -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.3/dist/leaflet.js"
     integrity="sha256-WBkoXOwTeyKclOHuWtc+i2uENFpDZ9YPdf5Hf+D7ewM="
     crossorigin=""></script>
<!-- CSS Bootstrap-->
     <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- JS Bootstrap-->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.6/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-oBqDVmMz9ATKxIep9tiCxS/Z9fNfEXiDAYTujMAeBAsjFuCZSmKbSSUnQlmh/jp3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-body-tertiary">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                  Dropdown
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                  <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link disabled">Disabled</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <form class="d-flex" role="search">
              <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
              <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    <div id="map">
        <script src="./js/leaflet.js"></script> 
    </div>
    <!--here -->
     <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js">      </script>
    <!-- here -->
</body>
</html>
```

So all that you are missing is the:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

before the body close tag

Answer (score 1):

You have included BOOTSTRAP twice!
delete this row from your head tag

> ```
> <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-mQ93GR66B00ZXjt0YO5KlohRA5SY2XofN4zfuZxLkoj1gXtW8ANNCe9d5Y3eG5eD" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
> ```

Working example without it: https://jsfiddle.net/MarinHTML/8kscdbn9/11/

------EDIT----- depricated old answer: ---

you're gonna need some JS to do the job here, because what you did is NEST a dropdown into another dropdown. Not sure if possible by simple bootstrap means. You can, but it must be on hover, and I presume you don't want that.

Here is a quick example of what I think you want:
https://jsfiddle.net/MarinHTML/t7zmqcd9/

And here is the JS to use it:

```
    let dds = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-toggle')
dds.forEach((dd)=>{
    dd.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        var el = this.nextElementSibling
        el.style.display = el.style.display==='block'?'none':'block'
    })
})
```

Comment: Why does he need to use javascript when bootstrap already does it for him simply by adding the bootstrap javascript script: `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
`

Comment: He already loaded the BS JS in the head tag, he doesn't need to add it

Comment: He hasn't done it correctly, check my snippet above. It totally works.

Comment: He did it correctly. Problem is - he did it twice. Now i saw it.